# Action-script - Creating a Counter for 10 seconds

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function that gets called from the parent, the function that contains the movie clip is imported and when i call the function my counter never seems to work and I'm displaying this counter in hours:minutes:seconds here is the code:

```
var seconds:int = 10000;


function startTimeLeftCounter():void{
trace("start");
txt_timeLeftText.visible = true;
txt_timeLeftCounter.visible = true;
seconds = seconds - 1000;
trace(seconds);
txt_timeLeftCounter.text = (Math.floor(seconds/60)) + ":" + (seconds % 60 >= 10 ? "": "0") + ":" +  (seconds % 60);
if(seconds > 0){ 
    setTimeout(startTimeLeftCounter, 1000);
}else{
    txt_timeLeftText.visible = false;
    txt_timeLeftCounter.visible = false;
    trace("finish");

}
}
```

The trace output i get straight away is (trace(seconds)):

```
start
-1000
finish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see only this trace is simple: "seconds" = 0 or undefined.
I don't see all code and place where you call function startTimeLeftCounter(), but I can to assume that the problem is that variable "seconds" in another scope or cleaning up by gc.

I tested your code local:

```
    private function testTimer():void {
        var seconds:int = 10000;

        function startTimeLeftCounter():void {
            trace("start");

            seconds = seconds - 1000;
            trace(seconds);

            if(seconds > 0) {
                setTimeout(startTimeLeftCounter, 1000);
            } else {
                trace("finish");

            }
        }

        startTimeLeftCounter();
    }
```

And have next trace:

```
[trace] start
[trace] 9000
[trace] start
[trace] 8000
...
[trace] start
[trace] 1000
[trace] start
[trace] 0
[trace] finish
```

Comment: Thankyou @Crabar, i never new you could nest functions.